# Perl: when doing 'open(A,"proc|")' make 'close(A)' return instantly

Tags: perl

If I do 'open(A,"proc|")', how do I make 'close(A)' return instantly, 
even if 'proc' hasn't finished writing to stdout?

"man perlfunc" tells me:

> Prematurely closing the read end of a pipe (i.e. before the  process
>   writing to it at the other end has closed it) will  result in a
>   SIGPIPE being delivered to the writer.  If the  other end can't handle
>   that, be sure to read all the data  before closing the pipe.

but is there a workaround? Specific example:

```
$|=1; 
open(A,"curl -sN http://test.barrycarter.info/bc-slow-cgi.pl|"); 

while (<A>) { 
  print "THUNK: $_\n"; 
  if (/5$/) {last;} 
} 

print "LOOP EXIT\n"; 
close(A); 
print "A CLOSED\n";
```

bc-slow-cgi.pl just prints time() once per second forever: the above 
code prints "LOOP EXIT", but never "A CLOSED".

Comment: What version of perl and curl do you have? Your code works as expected on perl 5.10.1 and curl 7.21.3. Some quick googling indicates there was some bug in an ancient version of curl that caused it not to exit on SIGPIPE

Comment: perl v5.10.0 and curl 7.19.7. I was going to upgrade, but I like @ikegami's solution better since it works for non-curl programs too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`close` on a handle created by `open -|` waits for the child to end. It seems to me that the child should die from a PIPE signal or error the next time it attempts to write after you call `close`, but you could kill the child if you don't want to wait that long.

```
my $pid = open(...);

while (...) {
   ...
}

kill PIPE => $pid;
close(...);
```

`PIPE` is a bit unorthodox, but it seemed appropriate here. Feel free to send `TERM` or whatever.